# When I type \in, it is going into the next line. Why?

Tags: math-mode, displaystyle

```
For \[R \in Q'\]
```

This what I have typed. 'For' is on the same line but the next expression is going onto the next paragraph and centered.

How can I avoid this?

Comment: Well because `\[ ... \]` is used to enter display math mode, which is used to display equations, setting them on their own line. You probably want `For $R \in Q'$` I guess. If you just want square brackets around things, then you just wanna type `[foo]`. Also `\( ... \)` may be used instead of `$ ... $` for inline math mode. You may come across `$$ ... $$` used elsewhere as an alternative to `\[ ... \]` to enter display math mode, or you may in fact already be familiar with it. `$$ ... $$` is deprecated and seriously discouraged. I only mention it to put you on your guard

Comment: @Au101 `$$...$$` is deprecated for use in LaTeX documents. It is not deprecated generally e.g. in plain TeX.

Comment: @cfr good point, sorry, my original comment was much shorter, but it occurred to me to add the `\( ... \)` alternative to `$ ... $` and then I thought it would be worth raising the issue of `$$ ... $$` and I wasn't thinking carefully enough to properly qualify my statements

Comment: @Au101 Well, the OP is presumably using LaTeX, judging by the syntax. So you are right in this context anyhow. I just thought it good to clarify ;).

Comment: @cfr Oh I agree :)

Comment: @Au101 Do you want to answer the question?

Answer (score 2):

The reason is that `\[ ... \]` is used to enter display math mode, which is used to display important equations that you wish to draw attention to. One of the things that it does is centre the equations and set them on their own line.

In your case, you probably want `For $R \in Q'$`, I guess.

If what you actually wanted was to type square brackets, then you just wanna type `[foo]`.

Also, just a bit more information. `\( ... \)` may be used instead of `$ ... $` for inline math mode. You may also come across `$$ ... $$` used elsewhere as an alternative to `\[ ... \]` to enter display math mode, or you may in fact already be familiar with it. [`$$ ... $$` is deprecated and seriously discouraged in LaTeX](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/503/why-is-preferable-to). I only mention it to put you on your guard.